# How can I debug webpack build script popularly

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm beginner to use webpack though enjoying programming so long time.
I configure it,and make it to output bundle script transpiled to from typescript,coffee-script so on. But I have no knowledge to debug bundled script with chrome dev-tools.I tried to set breakpoint coffee-script mapped chrome dev-tools first,though I thought it might not work,and of course, it didn't work.
How debug ordinarily these script ? Welcome any help.

**Edit:**
   I found why couldn't debug coffee in chrome dev-tools. Webpack loader didn't read all files because of failing preprocess javascript loading at browser. So runtime exits before reading file I want to debug. I can set breakpoint coffee map file. But, welcome any other tips.